# (jQuery) Calc distance element inside DIV

Tags: jquery, distance, calc

I have element `<div id="container">` and inside second element `<div id="element">`. I want calc distance element `<div id="element">` to the top first div in jQuery.

```
<div id="container">

   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <div id="element"></div>

</div>
```

How i can do this?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the distance in pixels between the top of `#container` and the top of `#element`?

Comment: I would like to measure the distance of the id= element to the top of the container in which it is, i.e. to the top of the id=container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `position()` to calculate the difference between the position of the two elements.

```
var dist = $('#element').position().top - $('#container').position().top;
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/5ucvb91x/